# jQuery UI: Draggable parent outline changes while dragging in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a draggable element inside a parent div. The parent has a css outline. In Firefox the outline of the parent changes size while dragging the child element. The outline expands so it always contains the draggable element. In Chrome and IE the parent div outline does not change, and the child element can be dragged out of the outline.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/knn2s8xs/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id=draggable>Drag Me!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    outline: 3px solid red;
    margin: 100px;
}

#draggable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery('#draggable').draggable({
    revert: true
});
```

Is there any way to get the same behavior in Firefox as in Chrome and IE?

Comment: I am having the same problem, in my case an outline is required instead of a border

Answer (score 0):

Use `border: 3px solid red;` that solves the problem!